# how we can add constraint ti our shema "compoudjs / jungglingdb"

Tags: compoundjs

i'm  a beginner, i start to use compoudjs and i use jungglingdb for the database and the module jungglung-postgres.
  my question is, how can i add constraint to created tables? 
  i try this
      var User = describe('User', function () {
                property('firstname', String);
                property('lastname', String);
                property('password', String,{ limit: 50);
                property('email', String {unique:true});
                property('approved', Boolean);
                set('restPath', pathTo.users);
                });
 but its not working

please help. 
tanks

Answer (score 0):

well i found a solution which is:

in  the file nodes_modules/jugglingdb-postgres/lib/prostgres.js
change the "datatype(p)" function to this by adding constraints for example:

```
    function datatype(p) {
 var q='';
if(p.unique!= undefined && p.unique)
{     q=' unique ';
 console.log(typeof(p.unique));
//
}
if(p.primaryKey!=undefined &&p.primaryKey)
{
    q=' primary key ';
}
if(p.notNull!=undefined &&p.notNull)
{
    q=' not null ';
}
if(p.check!=undefined )
{   //il faut definire manualement la condition de verification 
    q=' check('+p.check+') ';
    console.log(typeof(p.check));
}
if(p.constraintline!= undefined)
    q= ' '+p.constraintline;
if(p.constraint!= undefined)
    q= ' ,constraint '+p.constraint;
switch (p.type.name) {
    default:
    case 'String':
    case 'JSON':
    return 'varchar'+q;
    case 'Text':
    return 'text' +q;
    case 'Number':
    return 'integer' + q;
    case 'Date':
    return 'timestamp' + q;
    case 'Boolean':
    return 'boolean' + q;
}};
```